# Question about saving data

Tags: saving

I have a question about saving website coding data.

We want to save the data and html page coding of the pages we've created; so if I wanted to use that data to recreate the page, I could do so easily. The only way I know now is to go to each page and copy the html data from each page.

Is there a better and more efficient way to save the data, like a feature in the admin panel or something? I would appreciate any answers you can give me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your templates as files and edit them externally and EE will use them instead of the database version.

[old article but might help](https://cityzen.com/blog/saving-all-templates-to-files-quickly-in-expressionengine)

Documentation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAeJi.png). Also this [tip](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/templates_as_files.html) for changing in bulk.

Once they're external it makes it far easier it utilise version control and backup, I'd strongly advise in looking into Git - bit of an [old article but might help](https://cityzen.com/blog/saving-all-templates-to-files-quickly-in-expressionengine).

**Update**

If you want to copy an **entries** html, rather than the template, try [MX Cloner](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner) EE2 only.

Comment: I think he means that he wants to save the rendered page, not the template.

Comment: Oh. Whoops. I'll update with reference to MX Cloner. Should have made the question more clearer!

Answer (score 0):

CE_Cache has a static cache handler that saves the generated html to a file. You can then grab them from the cache folder. I don't know of any other addons that generate rendered html from pages. But they may exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CE Cache which generates static html-files. From the [CE Cache documentation](http://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-cache/user-guide/static.html):

> The server will check to see if the static driver has already made a flat html file of the requested page in the past. If a flat file is found, it will serve it up, completely bypassing ExpressionEngine®. If it has not, or if the page has expired, then the page will be requested from ExpressionEngine® and cached to a flat html file.

I use CE Cache but not with the static driver, because I always have some dynamic content here and there. So I am not sure how the cached data is structured, but as you can browse the files through the control panel I assume that they are structured in a handy way.

If you want to be sure just head over to the [CE Cache support forum at devot-ee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewforum/1867) and ask Aaron himself.